# Scroll to hash without name

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll

I try to scroll to a unnamed hash e.g. comment section but no luck

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('ANC: ' + location.hash);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: window.location.hash.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  }, 200);
});
```

Opening the link

```
http://example.com/foo/bar.html#1234567890
```

does not work with scrolling. I always get

> Uncaught TypeError: window.location.hash.offset is not a function

```
location.href=location.hash;
```

works just great but no scrolling which is too bad.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`hash` is just a string. Elements can have offsets, strings don't.

Try:

```
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Looks right buit does not work :( `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Comment: Only works if the `hash` identifies an actual element, by `id`. If the `hash` is just something used by the site's scripts to locate the *actual* element, this can't work. You'd need to first transform the hash to the actual element id.